# Plotly Dash Core components not rendering when set in call back and output to children

Tags: python, pandas, flask, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to have a set of dynamic controls in a dash app that changes upon input of a drop down. These values come from a pandas dataframe.

However, when i set the return value in the callback to be a dash core component eg. Dropdown, or Range slider - only the one declared in the layout renders, however the one in call back does not.

The layout looks like this:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    # Controls
    html.Div([

        #Top Layer Controls
        html.Div([

            #Project Dropdown
            html.Div([
                make_dropdown_menu(list(name_to_id.keys()), list(name_to_id.values()), id="project_selctor")
            ]),

            #date Slider
            html.Div(id = 'date_slider')

        ]),

        # State Controls

        html.Div([
            # Track State
            html.Div(id = 'track_state_dropdown_multi'),

            # Track Tags
            html.Div(id = 'track_tags_dropdown_multi'),

            # Track Changes
            html.Div(id = 'track_changes_dropdown_multi'),
        ]),

        # Filters

        html.Div([

            #Track Length
            html.Div(id = 'track_lenth_slider'),

            #Stop Numbers
            html.Div(id = 'number_of_stops_slider'),
        ]),

        html.Div(id = 'Selections')

    ])
])
```

and I have set up the call backs to look like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('track_state_dropdown_multi', 'children'),
    [Input("project_selctor", 'value')]
)
def update_project_df(value):
    filter_df = filter_track_data_by_project(track_data, value)

    menu = make_dropdown_menu(
        labels=filter_df.track_state.unique(),
        values=filter_df.track_state.unique(),
        id= "track_state_dropdown_comp",
        multi= True
    )
    return html.Div([menu])


@app.callback(
    Output('track_tags_dropdown_multi', 'children'),
    [Input("project_selctor", 'value')]
)
def update_project_df(project_selector):
    filter_df = filter_track_data_by_project(track_data, project_selector)
    menu = make_dropdown_menu(
        labels=list(set(flatten(filter_df.tags))),
        values = list(set(flatten(filter_df.tags))),
        id = 'track_tags_dropdown_comp',
        multi= True
    )
    return html.Div([menu])

@app.callback(
    Output('track_changes_dropdown_multi', 'children'),
    [Input("project_selctor", 'value')]
)
def update_project_df(project_selector):
    filter_df = filter_track_data_by_project(track_data, project_selector)
    track_changes = pd.DataFrame(flatten(filter_df.track_changes))
    menu = make_dropdown_menu(
        labels = track_changes.action.unique(),
        values = track_changes.action.unique(),
        id = "track_changes_dropdown_comp",
        multi = True

    )
    return html.Div([menu])

@app.callback(
    Output('track_length_slider', 'children'),
    [Input("project_selctor", 'value')]
)
def update_project_df(project_selector):
    filter_df = filter_track_data_by_project(track_data, project_selector)
    slider = dcc.RangeSlider(
        id = 'track_length_slider_comp',
        min = filter_df.track_lengh.min(),
        max = filter_df.track_lengh.max(),
        steps = 0.5

    )
    return html.Div([slider])

@app.callback(
    Output('number_of_stops_slider', 'children'),
    [Input("project_selctor", 'value')]
)
def update_project_df(project_selector):
    filter_df = filter_track_data_by_project(track_data, project_selector)
    slider = dcc.RangeSlider(
        id = 'number_of_stops_slider_comp',
        min = filter_df.number_of_stops.min(),
        max = filter_df.number_of_stops.max(),
        steps = 1

    )
    return html.Div([slider])

@app.callback(
    Output('Selections', 'children'),
    [Input('number_of_stops_slider_comp', 'value'),
    Input('track_changes_dropdown_comp', 'value')]
)
def update(stops, track):
    return('stops: {0}, tracks: {1}'.format(str(stops), str(track)))
```

And here are the relavent helper functions:

```
def make_dropdown_menu(labels, values, id, multi=False, **kwargs):
    options = []
    for i in range(len(labels)):
        d = dict(
            label = labels[i],
            value = values[i]
        )

        options.append(d)

    menu = dcc.Dropdown(
        id = id,
        options = options,
        value = options[0]['value'],
        style = {'width':'100%'}
    ) 
    return menu


def filter_track_data_by_project(df, proj_id):
    filtered_df = df[df.project_id ==  proj_id] 
    print(len(filtered_df))
    return filtered_df
```

It seems that the call back is never triggered since I have included a print function that never seems to be hit.

Any advice here would be helpful, except to declare the components in the layout which is not an option for the dynamic controls I wish to include.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation with Dash. Any component or callback that is not initialized with the layout will simply not function.

If you have a known number of possible components you want to activate/deactivate, you could load them into the layout inside containers with the style prop as `style=dict(display="none")`. Using a callback for each one, you could then show the component when you want it available, and hide it when you don't. This can be a burden, but it's really the only choice if you want a dynamic UI using Dash.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there documentation around these limitations that I would be able to reference along with my project as a github issue. Seems like quite an oversight. - For these kind of layourts, would you suggest I use Bokeh instead - or will I run into similar issues?

Comment: Yes, check out the "Gotchas" section of [this page](https://dash.plot.ly/faqs). I'm not really familiar with Bokeh, so I can't say. I have personally worked with layouts that involve  some dynamic changes to the UI components, and it's not great, but it isn't the worst either. However, if you plan to have most or all elements work this way, then it might be worth looking at other solutions.